# How can I make a "var" global or persistent?

Tags: c#, filesystems, var

I am writing an application that works with the file system. When the app first starts, it runs a quick routine to load the requested files and folders into memory for later (time intensive) processing. (See code below). At this point it gives me a count of how many files are going to be processed, which is important in order to display the progress bar.

Once I have the count and the file data, I need to store the data for later processing (e.g. as a global variable or property or class). The problem is that it is being stored as "var" by necessity since it is using LINQ. When I break and examine the variable, it is being stored as a rather complicated mix of SelectQueryOperator and AnonymousType.

My first thought was to go ahead and loop through the data and convert it to simple data that I can store as a List<>, (e.g. store filename and path) but doing that literally takes minutes - up to 10 minutes or more - to process. I am going to have to loop through all that data later anyway in order to do the processing, and there is no way my users are going sit and wait for a list to be built up first.

How can I store this data so that I can access it later without having to convert it into something else first?

```
var fileNames = 
from dir in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
select dir;

var fileContents = from file in fileNames.AsParallel() 
// Use AsOrdered to preserve source ordering 
let extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
let Text = File.ReadAllText(file)
select new { Text, FileName = file };
```

Comment: It is probably the File.ReadAllText that is taking the time. Do you need to do that here? Don't you want to just store the filenames for processing later?

Comment: You very possibly don't even have enough memory to store the entire text of all of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit, and also make `var` explicit where we can..

```
var fileNames = 
from dir in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
select dir;
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Which is exactly the same as:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Now for:

```
var fileContents = from file in fileNames.AsParallel() 
// Use AsOrdered to preserve source ordering 
let extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
let Text = File.ReadAllText(file)
select new { Text, FileName = file };
```

Going for a one-line-wonder doesn't normally help readability, but it will help put our object creation all in one place for the sake of discussion:

```
var fileContents = from file in fileNames.AsParallel() 
select new { Text = File.ReadAllText(file), FileName = Path.GetExtension(file) };
```

Which is a `ParallelQuery<T>` for an anonymous `T`. To make this something we can store we need to stop using anonymous classes:

```
private class NameAndContents
{
   public string Text{get;set;}
   public string FileName{get;set;}
}

ParallelQuery<NameAndContents> fileContents = from file in fileNames.AsParallel() 
select new NameAndContents{ Text = File.ReadAllText(file), FileName = Path.GetExtension(file) };
```

There's now nothing stopping you from storing that in a field of type `ParallelQuery<NameAndContents>`.

You might want to check on the logic here though in two ways:

1. The workings of `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is such that it needs to know the value of a given iteration in order to calculate the next. (It's based on the `FindNextFile` Windows API function). This makes it poor at being parallelised. Just how much the inherent waiting involved in `ReadAllText` balances that out is hard to predict. I'd not only test it against the non-parallel version, but I'd re-test after any changes made because any changes are going to throw off that balance in a new way.
2. The biggest hit here is that `ReadAllText`. If it's at all possible to replace that with something that makes use of the text in a more on-demand way, then it could be a big win.

Comment: Thank you (and everyone else quite frankly) for some very good information. More than anything else, this was an issue of a programmer (me) cutting and pasting code in a rush, and not understanding what is actually being coded. My goal was to get a list of the files I had to work with in the fastest way possible. I did NOT however need the ReadAllText, filesize or anything else, just a list of files/paths that I could later iterate through, and get a count from so I could display progress. Removing all the unnecessary bits made it super-duper fast, and left me with a nice list<string> to use.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that it is being stored as "var" by necessity since it is using LINQ.

No, there's nothing about LINQ that *requires* you to use `var`. Basically `var` allows you to use anonymous types in a strongly typed way within a method.

All you need to do is convert your anonymous type into a named type, and you'll have exactly the same *performance* as you would with `var`. The difference you were seeing when you used `ToList` was simply that until you *evaluate* the query, it's not going to actually do anything - I suspect you weren't hitting the file system at all. (It's not clear why you have a query expression for `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in the first place.)

Either you need to load the data early or you don't - it's not really clear from your question, but the `var` part is entirely orthogonal to that.

As an aside, using parallel processing on a file system may well be hindering rather than helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `var` for any non-local variables.  ([This is why.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx))  You could, if you really, really hate the person who needs to maintain your code just store it as an `object` or `dynamic` and use one of several possible hacks for getting the information out of an anonymous type that has been stored as an `object`, but that's probably not a good idea.

Really, your best bet is to just create a new type with a `Text` and `FileName` properties and use that rather than an anonymous type.  It's by the simplest and least mean to future developers of your options.

Answer (score 0):

Loading all the data up front and keeping it around for later processing is almost always the wrong idea. What you should be doing is loading the files one by one and processing them as you go, in which case you do not need to store anything.

To address the letter of your question: you would simply project the results of the operation to anything other than an anonymous type. For example, you could make a class:

```
class FileData
{
    string FileName { get; set; }
    string Contents { get; set; }
}

var fileContents = from file in fileNames
                   select new FileData
                   {
                       FileName = Path.GetExtension(file),
                       Contents = File.ReadAllText(file)
                   };
```

As long as you *do not* call `.ToList()` or similar on this variable, you can enumerate the files and their contents on the fly.

Sidenote: I removed the `.AsParallel()` call because this operation's bottleneck would be the filesystem, not the CPU.

Comment: I agree with this in principle, but there is not enough information about Todd's requirements to suggest this course at this time.  Unless you are privy to more information about Todd's application than is mentioned in the post.

Comment: Me too. Parallel processed enumerator on a file system = asking for it in my book.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
        List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Do you really need to actually read every file?

By the way, var is not dynamic typing, var is just compiler shorthand for "compiler, write the type of the right side for me here so I can avoid having code like

```
List<type> a = new List<type>()
```

Any time you see "var", it can be replaced with the actual type.

I also don't see how "AsParallel" is supposed to help here.